# React js know if I have focus on the page I am viewing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way in react js to determine that the page I am viewing is in focus.

Possible scenario, I have two tabs open, when I am not on the tab that should tell me if it has focus or not, I would like a variable to be set that indicates that the page does not have focus, in order to perform actions.

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-meadow-ri14n?file=/src/App.js)

Code:

```
import "./styles.css";

import React from "react";

// User has switched back to the tab
const onFocus = () => {
  console.log("Tab is in onfocus");
  document.title = "Tab is in onfocus";
};

const offFocus = () => {
  console.log("Tab is in offfocus");
  document.title = "Tab is in offfocus";
};

// User has switched away from the tab (AKA tab is hidden)
const onBlur = () => {
  console.log("Tab is blurred");
  document.title = "Tab is blurred";
};

const WindowFocusHandler = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("focus", onFocus);
    //window.addEventListener('blur', onBlur);

    // Specify how to clean up after this effect:
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("focus", offFocus);
      //window.removeEventListener('blur', onBlur);
    };
  });

  return <></>;
};

export default WindowFocusHandler;
```

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: what's the problem? your code looks good, uncomment blur. Also put the dependencies to useEffect(()=> {}, [])

Answer (score 1):

You can use the visibilitychange event in plain javascript. See the link below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event

Or use something like shown on the link given below.

https://blog.sethcorker.com/harnessing-the-page-visibility-api-with-react